# Include inside sidebar

Tags: sidebar, include

Is it possible to include a file inside or inbetween items in a sidebar?

Here are the two functions being called:

```
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_template_part('testimonial-box'); ?>
```

The sidebar has 3 elements inside which appear on the page when rendered. I'd like the testimonial box to appear after the first. If I switch the two functions around it'll be:

TESTIMONIAL
SIDEBAR ITEMS

I need:

SIDEBAR ITEM #1
TESTIMONIAL
SIDEBAR ITEM #2
SIDEBAR ITEM #3

At all possible?

Comment: I think that the simplest and esiest solution is to create a widget for your sidebar to include whatever you want.

Comment: @cybmeta have the exact same thing in mind while reading the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want you can use this plugin: [PHP Text Widget](https://wordpress.org/plugins/php-text-widget/)

This allows you to use a text widget and use your choice of php codes in the text widget and achieve whatever you want.

I hope this helps